# Find all combinations that not contains a specific string

Tags: python, filtering, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Is there any way to find all combinations of an array that not contains specific substrings?
For example
`a=['a','b','c'] aaa aab aac aba abb ... ccc`

but i don't want the substring `ab` so `aaa aac aca acb ... ccc`
I use the code bellow but for combination of `20` chars and comb of `13` it takes too much time

```
import itertools

lista=[]
def foo(l):
    yield from itertools.product(*([l] * 3)) 

non=["ab"]

for x in foo('abc'):
    x=(''.join(x))
    for j in non:
        if j in x:
            value=1
            break
        else:
            value=0
    if (value==0):
        lista.append(x)
```

Comment: I think you should check out regex in python

Comment: Why not use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement('abc',3)`.

Comment: @Ch3steR Wouldn't produce 'aca'.

Comment: You have 20 characters and you want to check all combinations of 13 characters with replacement?  This is 13^20 different combinations.  Your list will be gigantic.  Is there a specific reason you need to do this?  Is there any more detail you can provide on why you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating all strings then rejecting the ones containing any forbidden substrings, it is (asymptotically) more efficient to build the strings by backtracking, and reject any partial string which already contains a forbidden substring. We only need to test if the current partial string *ends* with any forbidden substring, which is faster than testing if it *contains* one.

Here's an implementation using a recursive generator function:

```py
def strings_without(alphabet, k, avoid):
    def helper(s):
        if any(s.endswith(t) for t in avoid):
            pass
        elif len(s) == k:
            yield s
        else:
            for c in alphabet:
                yield from helper(s + c)
    return helper('')
```

Example:

```py
>>> for s in strings_without('abc', 3, ['ab']):
...     print(s)
... 
aaa
aac
aca
acb
acc
baa
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

For strings of length 13 from an alphabet of size 20, this should be a big improvement, but 20<sup>13</sup> is an enormous number. So unless you are forbidding a lot of substrings, the number of solutions will be very large. No algorithm can possibly generate *h* strings of length *k* in less than O(*hk*) time, so the running time for any efficient algorithm will still be [output-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm).